# Scrapy login authentication not working

Tags: python, scrapy, mechanize

I have just started playing around with scrapy. I am trying to crawl a website that requires login. I got it working just fine for github. I found the form id, added the required fields and everything went on as planned.

However, when I tried the same on the investopedia website, I got into troble. I am attaching the code.

```
class Investo_spider(InitSpider):
    name = 'investo_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['investopedia.com']
    login_page = 'http://www.investopedia.com/accounts/login.aspx'
    start_urls = ['http://www.investopedia.com']

    def init_request(self):
        return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
            return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                               formdata={'email': 'mymail','password': 'mypass'},
                               callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        if "myname" in response.body:
            self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
            self.initialized()
        else:
            self.log("Login was unsuccessful")


    def parse_item(self, response):
        print 'I got in here, finally!!!!'
        pass
```

I have tried adding the formnumber=0,clickdata={'nr': 0} and changing the method (POST or GET) although the defaults were already selecting the right form and clickable.

Surprisingly, I got it working on a mechanize browser, using the same parameters. I can convert the html to a HtmlResponse object that scrapy can process.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.investopedia.com/accounts/login.aspx")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form["email"] = 'mymail'
br.form["password"] = 'mypass'
br.submit()
br.open('http://www.investopedia.com')
response = HtmlResponse(url="some_url"),body=br.response().read())
```

However, this would mean I would have to carry the mechanize browser around, which I assume is not the best of solutions. I think I might be missing something. I would really appreciate your input on this. Thanks!

Comment: Scrapy doesn't handle very well aspx forms, I've run into this before, I just ended up using selenium to do the login and save the cookies and let scrapy use them. Try to `yield` a request instead of returning in `init_request`

Comment: Try to also submit `{'remember': '1'}`

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Would you have a sample working code for selenium? @kev The `{'remember': '1'}` additional submit had no effect. I am thinking about going for the mechanize option, though it is not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to handle redirection. this will work for you.

```
class Investo_spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'investo_spider'
allowed_domains = ['investopedia.com']
login_page = 'http://www.investopedia.com/accounts/login.aspx'
start_urls = ['http://www.investopedia.com']

def init_request(self):
    return scrapy.Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest('http://www.investopedia.com/accounts/login.aspx',
                                     formdata={'email': 'you_email', 'password': 'your_password',
                                               'form_build_id': 'form - v14V92zFkSSVFSerfvWyH1WEUoxrV2khjfhAETJZydk',
                                               'form_id': 'account_api_form',
                                               'op': 'Sign in'
                                               },
                                     meta = {'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list':[302]},
                                     callback=self.check_login_response)

def check_login_response(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request('http://www.investopedia.com/accounts/manageprofile.aspx', self.validate_login)

def validate_login(self, response):
    if "myname" in response.body:
        self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
        self.initialized()
    else:
        self.log("Login was unsuccessful")

def parse_item(self, response):
    print 'I got in here, finally!!!!'
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Usman, but this does not seem to be the issue. The login is still unsuccessful.

Comment: This code is running fine for me. i have made a demo user and perform login using scrapy. it works fine.